# upload react app to heroku to install devDependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, npm, dependencies

I create react app with create-react-app and I uploaded the app to heroku. when I try to show the website I see the error

[image]

my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "admin-managment-barber",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines":{
    "node":"8.11.3",
    "npm":"6.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "icheck": "^1.0.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "mobx": "^5.6.0",
    "mobx-persist": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.2",
    "mobx-react-router": "^4.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.20.2",
    "react-datepicker": "1.6.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-icheck": "^0.3.8",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-ladda": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select": "^2.1.2",
    "react-switchery-component": "^0.0.7",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "react-toastify": "^4.4.3",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "validatorjs": "^3.15.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "heroku-prebuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false; export NODE_ENV=; NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false NODE_ENV=development npm install --only=dev --dev",
    "heroku-postbuild": "export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true; export NODE_ENV=production;"

  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
          "legacy": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

I tried also with the default scripts when create the react project

```
     "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",

  },
```

but I get the same issue.
I read some posts on stackoverflow but without any working solution for my issue.
what I think is that when it's run on heroku server it's not install devDependencies, only the dependencies.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning

Comment: I run it now "heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false" but still same error.